# How to get string from EditText on clicking ok on android keyboard?

Tags: java, android

How do i get string from EditText field after clicking on android virtual keyboard?

I used addTextChangedListener, but it looks like i'm getting text right after i type a symbol in the text field. I expected it to get full string, not everytime i type something

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `setOnKeyListener` event instead of the `addTextChangedListener` event.

You can do something like this:

```
 final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
 edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
  public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
      if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
          (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Perform your action and get the text 
          String strInput = edittext.getText().toString();
          if (strInput != null && strInput.trim().equals("")) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a value", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
          }        
         return true;
      }
     return false;
  }
});
```

Reference doc: [Android View OnKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener)

**UPDATE**

One more way is to add the `imeOptions` as a part of the `EditText` and use the following code to get the string entered by the user.

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new 
EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
   @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
      //do here your stuff here
      return true;
    }
    return false;
   } 
});
```

In your XML file, add the following properties to `EditText`:

```
<EditText
  ...
  android:inputType="text"
  android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

Comment: I added imeOptions to EditText and it worked. Is it normal? Or i should use your solution? What's the difference?
https://pastebin.com/k2J5tM08

Comment: Yes. You can use `imeOptions` as well for this. Please see my updated answer. In both cases my solution would help you.